# Need help visualizing mass and momentum diffusivity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, mass

I'm currently studying various dimensionless numbers. Right now, I'm stuck trying to understand the Schmidt number.

I think I understand what is meant by thermal diffusivity. It's just how fast heat spreads in a fluid.

But I don't quite understand mass and momentum diffusivity. Is mass diffusivity just how fast the fluid's particles move? Is momentum diffusivity just how fast the particles in the fluid collide with each other?

What's an example of mass diffusivity? Of momentum diffusivity? I was thinking that the propagation of sound is related to momentum diffusivity since it involves the transfer of momentum.

I've been looking up explanations online of the Schmidt number and some explanations show things like the hydrodynamic layer and concentration boundary layer. I also don't quite grasp those two concepts.

Any help would be great!

Comment: The thermal diffusivity is $\frac{C_P\mu}{k}$